# PYQT QTimer Not Entering the Handler Def

Tags: python, pyqt, qtimer

I've got the following code which works in my mainwindow but I need to duplicate it in a pop up window.  When ran it doesn't enter the handler def and I'm not sure why.  I've tried everything I can think of.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

CurrentTime = 0

class widgetWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        super(widgetWindow, self).__init__()
        widgetWindow.start(self)

    def start(self):
        window = QtGui.QMainWindow(self)
        window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        CentralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        timeSlider = QtGui.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, self)
        CentralWidgetLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        VBox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        CentralWidgetLayout.addWidget(timeSlider)
        VBox.addLayout(CentralWidgetLayout)
        CentralWidget.setLayout(VBox)
        window.setCentralWidget(CentralWidget)
        timeSlider.setValue(0)
        window.show()

        self.runTimer()

    def runTimer(self):

        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTime)
        timer.start(1000)

    def updateTime(self):
        global CurrentTime
        CurrentTime = CurrentTime + 1
        print("Current Timer = ", CurrentTime)



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = widgetWindow()
    win.show()
    win.resize(800,450)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here

1)

In your `main` function, the line

```
win.show()
```

is redundant. Remove it and you will see your `QMainWindow` object

2)

You did not hold a reference to your timer object.

Change the `runTimer` to this and it should work

```
def runTimer(self):

    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTime)
    self.timer.start(1000)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it worked perfectly.  I forgot to also ask how to get CurrentTime to update the timeSlider (QSlider).  If you could point me in the right direction I would once again be very grateful. @AnthonKong

Comment: If u find the solution useful, please accept it as an answer. It is also better to ask additional question in a new post. Cheers